# Captions alignment in ToT or ToF

Tags: table-of-contents, alignment

I have customized the table of tables and the table of figures to make it a double column.
But I am struggling with aligning the content to the left, it seems like it is getting justified. (refer to the image attached). How can I fix this?
[image]

## MWE

MWE.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{MWE}
\LoadClass[9pt, oneside]{extbook}
\RequirePackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{l}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage{tocloft,calc}
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{themecolor}{RGB}{8,156,228}

%  I think the problem is in this code - 4 lines below
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{-20pt}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpagefont}{\fontsize{7pt}{8pt}\selectfont\color{themecolor}}
\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\quad}
\setlength{\cftsetrmarg}{5cm}

\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \chapter*{\fontsize{38pt}{39pt}\clearmedium\selectfont\listfigurename}
    \setlength\columnsep{1.5cm}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \end{multicols}
}
}
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass{MWE}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{MWE}
\author{}
\date{October 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\listoffigures

\chapter{Test}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{./test.png}
    \caption{Nunc consequat leo ut ex dignissim diroin sit amet efficitur metus}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Following is the compiled output of MWE, I don't want the extra white space that is highlighted with the red colour underlines.

[image]

Comment: How have you done the customization? Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows what you have done and what your problem is.

Comment: @PeterWilson Added MWE.

Comment: Your stated problem is with List of Tables in two columns but your MWE only shows a single figure.

Comment: @PeterWilson I have updated the compiled output of the MWE in question, I don't want the extra white space highlighted with the red colour underlines.

Comment: @PeterWilson any update on this?

Comment: Not from me. I leave it up to someone else. To me your MWE ouptut looks OK.